# -Like returning True incorrectly

Tags: powershell

My expectation is this code as shown would return False, but I am actually getting a True for every key in $taskVars.

```
$source = 'C:\Assets\_Px Tools\Tasks\Move_Ex\Source\$(fileName).txt'
$taskVars = @{
    fileName = '[PxFileName]'
    fileDate = '[PxFileDate]'
    fileTime = '[PxFileTime]'
    fileDateTime = '[PxFileDateTime]'
}

$foundTaskVar = $false
foreach ($var in $taskVars.keys) {

    Write-Host "*$($taskVars.$var)*"
    if ($source -like "*$($taskVars.$var)*") {
        $foundTaskVar = $true
        Write-Host "$($taskVars.$var)!"
    }
}
```

I've got some Write-Hosts in there to verify the contents of the variables and the search criteria are as expected, and for the life of me I can't see why anything returns $true, say nothing of everything.

```
$source = 'C:\Assets\_Px Tools\Tasks\Move_Ex\Source\[PxFileName].txt'
```

should return true, but not

```
$source = 'C:\Assets\_Px Tools\Tasks\Move_Ex\Source\$(fileName).txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets in your variables have a special meaning to `-like`.  It thinks you want it to match any of the characters inside the bracket (e.g. 'p' or 'x' or ...).  If you escape the first bracket with a backtick (`), I think you will get what you want:

```
$taskVars = @{
    fileName = '`[PxFileName]'
    fileDate = '`[PxFileDate]'
    fileTime = '`[PxFileTime]'
    fileDateTime = '`[PxFileDateTime]'
}
```

Get more information in the help:

[about_Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6)

Incidentally, I think a hashtable is a bit overkill for what you ware doing here.  A simple array would work just as well.

Comment: Note that you could use `[Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape('[PxFileName]')`, etc.

Comment: It's not just "overkill", it's the wrong tool for the job entirely.

Comment: The key with the hash table is it is being used for a different but related purpose, so rather than also create an array with just the values, and have to coordinate the two, I just reused the hash here as well.

Comment: @boxdog Interesting. I had always thought -like specifically didn't have special characters beyond wild cards like * and ?. Matching a range of characters is new to me. FWIW, it seems like both square brackets need escaped. So in the end, using -Match instead, with [regex]::escape  to treat everything in the search string as literals, does the trick.

Comment: @Gordon incidentally this is also why there's a difference between `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` parameters to input/ouptut cmdlets if your folder or filename might have `[]` characters in it.